# macOS x: boost .hpp not found compiling qt5 project with make

Tags: boost, qt5, qmake, clang++

I am trying to build an example qt5 project where Makefile is built with qmake.  clang++ gives me this error:

fatal error: 'boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp' file not found

Since Makefile is generated by qmake, it is difficult edit the huge Makefile -I include paths to find boost header files ( which is in /usr/local/include/boost ).

Is there a way to specify additional include paths in qmake that would help?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can add include paths to the qmake file using INCLUDE_PATH

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath

```
# add homebrew include path only on MacOS
macx:INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/local/include"
```

Comment: Ok.  I did manage to solve the problem by putting a symbolic link to the boost folder in my project directory, but I think your answer is more elegant.

Comment: Are you sure about the macx tag?  Does this directive go in the source file ( main.cpp in my case ), Makefile or where?  qmake doesn't gives this error:  main.cpp:1:1: error: unknown type name 'macx'
macx:INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/local/include"

Comment: Nevermind.  After more bumbling around, it goes in the .pro file.  Thanks..

Comment: Great that this helped you. qmake is very powerful, and you can basically do anything and never have to edit the Makefile (which will be overwritten on the next run of qmake anyways). The Qt documentation has a [very good tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-tutorial.html.).
Can you accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark left to it?